# Get remote working directory of existing SSH session

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, sshd

Suppose I've got an SSH session to a remote host, and let's say I know the PID of that session on my local machine. I'm trying to come up with a way for a process *on my local machine* to programmatically get that SSH session's working directory *on the remote host*.

Here's the best way I've come up with.

```
$ sh -c "$(cat /proc/$SSH_PID/cmdline | tr '\0' ' ')\
     'readlink /proc/\$(pgrep -P \
         \$(pgrep -u \$(whoami) sshd | tail -n2 | head -n1)\
     \$(basename \$SHELL))/cwd'"
```

In other words, get the command line from the existing SSH session by PID, then run it again with a command to read the CWD of the shell of the second-to-last connection made by sshd by this user (since the last would be the connection running the command itself).

This is clearly not a very robust or elegant solution. Is there a better way?

Comment: The biggest problem with my solution is that it only gets the most recent ssh connection made by that user. So if I have two SSH sessions open to this machine and I want to get the first, I don't have a good way of doing that.

Comment: Don't have time to write a proper answer with example code, but if you have root access to both machines you could use a **netstat  --tcp -np|grep ssh**; that way you can match port numbers to PID and be **sure** you have the right process on the far end.

Comment: Ooh, good idea. That could get foiled by a firewall's NAT, though. And, as you say, it needs root on both machines...